# What exactly it denotes when a key inside a JavaScript object is in square braces

Tags: javascript

```
  const sample=  {
                   [name]:value
                 }
```

What exactly the above JavaScript object represents

Comment: it means to use the variable `name` and the value it holds as the key, not `"name"` as the key.

Comment: This is not JSON, but a JavaScript Object. JSON is a string based representation of data. And the square braces would not be a valid syntax in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This means name is variable

like

```
let name = 'John';

 const sample=  {
                   [name]:value
                 }
```

So sample will be like this

```
sample.John = value
```

Try this

```js
let name = 'John';

 const sample=  {
                   [name]:"I am John"
                 }
                 
console.log(sample);
```